# Geometry Nodes, Invert Selection

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using Geometry nodes, I wanted to invert my selection. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct node for this purpose but it won't let me plug the node as seen on the image below:

[image: reference node]

For my current use case, I could probably get away with the following setup:

[image: reference image, workaround]

but I wanted to know how to invert selection for when the need arises.

I tried to search for [blender "geometry nodes" "reverse selection"] and [blender "geometry nodes" "invert selection"] but nothing came out useful.

ADDENDUM:

Hi Chris, thanks for your answer, it directly answered the title of my question. But I want to expand this a bit more. Here's why:

If I cascade two Triangulate nodes, it produces this:

[image: ref image, cascaded triangulate]

In effect, It retained the integrity of the whole geometry.

While using Separate Geometry, it broke my geometry into two:

[image: ref, using separate geometry]

In effect, I lost some of the details of my input geometry:

[image: ref image, comparing results]

I'm pretty sure I used the wrong node (the Separate Geometry Node) which I mentioned in my initial question because that's the only node that I had in mind. But, if I wanted actually reverse the selection of my previous node without actually separating the two geometries, how would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selection as Input is a boolean value (you can determine it by its pink color).

The green color indicates that it is geometry. So maybe "Selection" is not the best word here for the outputed selected geometry, but that's what it is: selected geometry.

Here an example:

[image]

I seperate (divide) the geometry into two parts.

The selected part (selection) where z > 0 which will be red.
The inverted geometry where z < 0 which will be green.

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: hi Chris, once again, thanks for the answer. I updated my question to make my intention clearer :)

Comment: i am not totally sure what you want to achieve? did you try "face" instead of point in separate geometry node? is that what you want? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lddc.jpg

Comment: oh wow, yeah i missed that one  thanks again Chris! :)

Comment: @Sophia Since _Selection_ is a boolean value as Chris pointed out, another possibility would be to invert the result of the _Greater Than_ output directly: use the _Utilities_ > _Boolean Math_ node set to "Not". This inverts the boolean selection so that you can plug it in any _Selection_ input if it is needed.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will give that a try :)